# Spring boot with SpringFox Swagger UI Generates all Verbs

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I enabled API documentation using Swagger 2.6.1 in my spring boot app. The page(swagger-ui.html) loads fine but controller documentation contains all the verbs(PUT, GET, PATCH, POST, etc) even if my controller only has a GET operation. How can I disable the other verbs in the UI doc?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you have mapping like this in your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/productDetails")
```

Springfox cannot identify what is the requestMethod hence it provides all mapping.(Eventhough the default is GET)

If you change this to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/productDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Then you will see only GET mapping and not others.
If you use newer versions of Sprinboot, you can use `@GetMapping` or `@PostMapping` instead of `@RequestMapping`